# Array intersect inside a while loop

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I am trying to with `array_intersect` match variable sku to the csv file,
When running it it causes a white page

```
while (($result = fgetcsv($ocuk,1024,"\t")) !== false)
    {
        $csvfull[] = $result;
    }

$count=count($csvfull);
$sku = array();

foreach ($csvfull as $row)
    {
        $sku[] = $row[1];
    }
$csv = fgetcsv($ocuk);
while ($x <= $count)
    {
        array_intersect($sku[$x], $csv)
            echo
            '',$csv[1], //sku
            'test<br>';
        $x++;
    }
```

All I require is for `array_intersect` to check for sku in the csv file and then display the information requested from the csv file

example

`sku = fb706`, the array intersect finds it in the csv file then displays column 1 in the csv files

Comment: You might want to use `in_array` instead, as well as an if statement (what if sku is not present)

Comment: i dnt think it is but added the other code above it as that might help identify the best solution

Answer (score 0):

Is your `$csv` variable just a one dimensional array of skus? Seems unlikely but if thats the case then use `in_array`

```
while ($x <= $count)
{
    if(in_array($sku[$x], $csv){
        //the sku is present in the array
    }
    $x++;
}
```